# Iterate through 2d vector

Tags: c++

I try to create a Graph class and want to print all Edges to the screen. But I have a problem iterating a 2d vector.

```
class Graph
{
public:
    Graph(void);
    ~Graph(void);
    vector<Node*> nodes;
    void addNode(Node node);
    void addDirectedEdge(Node &head,Node* tail,int cost);
    void toSrceen();
};

class Node
{
public:
    Node(char* name);
    ~Node(void);
    char* name;
    vector<Node*> children;
    vector<int> costs;

};

void Graph::toSrceen()
{
    for (vector<vector<Node*>>::iterator i = nodes.begin(); i != nodes.end();++i) 
    {
         for (vector<Node*>::iterator j = i->begin(); j != i->end();++i)
         {
             cout << j->name;
         }
     }
}
```

There is a problem in the first for loop but i can not find the mistake...

Comment: What sort of problem?  It's much easier to find what's wrong if we don't have to guess at what went wrong.

Comment: Add a space between the closing angles `> >`

Comment: @ChristianAmmer that compiler bug has been fixed for some time.

Comment: @AJG85: Thanks for the good news, I'm suprised because I always wrote the extra space and have not realized the change.

Comment: @AJG85: In which compiler? I just recently had to add in the space in a project being compiled with g++ 4.something with std=c++98

Comment: Since VS2005 and g++ 4.5 I believe ... don't quote me though. It certainly is fixed in VS2010 and g++ 4.6 which we are using now.

Comment: @ChristianAmmer FYI we use C++11 features as well but I believe that's unrelated.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the inner loop increments the wrong iterator.   Probably needs to be:

```
 for (vector<Node*>::iterator j = i->begin(); j != i->end();++j)
```

Comment: +1 eagle eyes. Also worth mentioning that `const_iterator` should be used when possible.

Answer (score 0):

You're incrementing "i" each iteration of the second loop rather than j.

Comment: Well the i is just a copy-paste error. But i cannot compile the code because in the for loop the compiler expects vector<Node>. But every Node has a vector<Node> itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<vector<Node*>>::iterator i = nodes.begin()
```

if you look at the declaration of Graph::nodes, it's a `vector<Node*>`, not a `vector<vector<Node*>>`

the loop should probably be something like:

```
void Graph::toSrceen()
{
    for (vector<Node*>::iterator i = nodes.begin(); i != nodes.end();++i) 
    {
         Node* currNode = *i;
         for (vector<Node*>::iterator j = currNode->children.begin(); j != currNode->children.end();++j)
         {
             cout << j->name;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... The code compiles now. But inner loop i get an exception "vector iterators incompatible" :(